# Android Reading and writing a file to and from an array

Tags: android, arrays, file, io

First I will say I've researched various solutions on StackOverflow and elsewhere and none have solved my issue.  I'll admit that my knowledge in this area is somewhat lacking, so sorry for being all noobish.

I want to do what I assume to be a simple thing.  My app creates a file on start up if it does not exist yet, and populates it with 30 "0.0", each on a different line (This is done successfully).

Then when you beat a level, the intent is to have the file read, the 0.0's and assign each one to an element of an array, assign the time remaining (for example, 2.5) to the appropriate spot ([0] for the first level, [1] for the second level, etc), and write it back to the file to keep track of how much time was remaining when the player beat each level.

The problem becomes, though it does write the score in the appropriate spot back into the file (I'm testing level 1 so in spot [0]), all of the other 0.0's become "null".  So I know there is a mistake somewhere that I must not be seeing, and after several hours over several days of trying various solutions, I finally decided to ask for help here.  This is the code below:

```
try {
        String[] scoreArray = new String[30];
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File myFile = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath());
   // myFile.createNewFile();
    File file = new File(myFile, "RLGLscores.txt");
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                            new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(fis));
    String data = "";
    int i = 0;
    while ((data = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
            scoreArray[i] = data;
        i++;

    }
    myReader.close();
    scoreArray[0] = timerStringFormat;

    for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
    myOutWriter.write(scoreArray[j] + newLine);
    }

    myOutWriter.close();
    fOut.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

timerStringFormat is the String that holds the time remaining in the form of a String.  Again I'm rather new to this.  My game is nearly complete, I'm amazed I got as far as I have.  But any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Opening the file for writing truncates it to zero length. If you later try to read from it you just see an empty file.

To fix that, first read the contents, close the reader, and then open the output stream and write the modified contents back.